# Basic Grassmann/Berezin Integral Question

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, integration, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Is there a reason why $\int\! d\theta~\theta = 1$ for a Grassmann integral? Books give arguments for $\int\! d\theta = 0$  which I can follow, but not for the former one.

Answer (score 11):

Let $\theta$ denote a [Grassmann-odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) variable.

1. If an integral
   $$I~:=~\int\! d\theta\tag{1}$$
   on the algebra ${\cal A} $ of superfunctions $f(\theta)=\theta a + b$ should be

   - a (graded) linear operation,
   - translation invariant
     $$\int\! d\theta ~f(\theta+\theta_0) ~=~\int\! d\theta~f(\theta),$$
   - and the output $\int\! d\theta~ f(\theta)$ should not depend on the integration variable $\theta$ (apart from $a$ and $b$),

   then it is easy to check that the usual [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) for the [Berezin integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_integral) is the only possibility up to an overall multiplicative normalization factor.

   Interestingly, this means that Berezin integration $\int\! d\theta$ is the same as differentiation $\partial / \partial\theta$ !
2. If a [definite integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DefiniteIntegral.html)
   $$I(\theta_1,\theta_2)~\stackrel{?}{:=}~\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta\tag{2}$$
   on the algebra ${\cal A} $ of superfunctions $f(\theta)=\theta a + b$ should be

   - a (graded) linear operation,
   - translation invariant
     $$\int_{\theta_1+\theta_0}^{\theta_2+\theta_0}\! d\theta ~f(\theta+\theta_0) ~=~ \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta~f(\theta),$$
   - the output $\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta~ f(\theta)$ should only depend on the limits $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (apart from $a$ and $b$),
   - and vanishes for closed contours
     $$\begin{align}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_1}\! d\theta~f(\theta)~=~&0, \tag{i}\cr \left( \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}+\int_{\theta_2}^{\theta_1}\right) d\theta~f(\theta)~=~&0,\tag{ii}\cr
      \left( \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}+\int_{\theta_2}^{\theta_3}+\int_{\theta_3}^{\theta_1}\right) d\theta~f(\theta)~=~&0,\tag{iii} \end{align}$$

   then it is easy to check that the definite integral
   $$\begin{align}I(\theta_1,\theta_2)~\stackrel{?}{:=}~&\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta\tag{2}\cr
   ~~~\propto~&~~ (\theta_2-\theta_1)\int\! d\theta\tag{2'}\end{align}$$
   is proportional to $(\theta_2-\theta_1)$ times the usual Berezin integration $\int\! d\theta$.

   *Sketched proof of eq. (2'):*
   $$\begin{align}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta~ f(\theta)~=~&P(\theta_1,\theta_2)\cr
   ~=~&A\theta_1\theta_2+B_1\theta_1+B_2\theta_2+C\end{align}$$
   must be a second-order polynomial in $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (where the coefficients $A,B_1,B_2,C$ depend linearly on $a,b$). The condition (i) implies $B_1+B_2=0$ and $C=0$, while (iii) implies $A=0$. Translation invariance shows that the integral cannot depend on $b$. $\Box$

   This definite integral (2') is manifestly [soul](https://planetmath.org/supernumber)-valued, and hence not very useful. It also violates the naive expectation that the definite integration (2) should reverse Grassmann-parity. Moreover, the rule for integration by substitution $\theta^{\prime}=t\theta$ is non-standard:
   $$ \int_{\theta^{\prime}_1=t\theta_1}^{\theta^{\prime}_2=t\theta_2}\! d\theta^{\prime}~f(\theta^{\prime})~~=~~\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\! d\theta~f(t\theta),$$
   i.e. there is no Jacobian factor! For this and other reasons, the definite integral (2) is usually considered to be ill-defined.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449312/11127) related Math.SE post.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a better answer than I've ever found. Condition (3) is what I was missing, and I assume that it is true since the Berezin integral is to be thought of as a definite integral, and finite at that?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: The answer explains (sort of) why  ∫dθ θ=1 "up to an overall multiplicative normalization factor". So we could have also defined it as 7. Or $\pi$. Or $i$. Is there any reason why 1 makes more sense than others, or is it just the "simplest" non-zero number so it was chosen?

Comment: It is just a matter of convention.