# Why is the Jacobian factor for fermionic variables different from that for bosonic ones?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

In Srednicki's textbook [Quantum Field Theory](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), Section 77 discusses anomalies and the path integral for fermions. The path integral over the Dirac field is defined to be

\begin{equation}
Z(A) \equiv \int \mathcal{D}\Psi\mathcal{D}\overline{\Psi} e^{iS(A)}  \tag{77.8}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
S(A) \equiv \int d^{4}x \overline{\Psi}i\displaystyle{\not}{D}\Psi                \tag{77.9}
\end{equation}
is the Dirac action, $i\displaystyle{\not}{D}= i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}$ is the Dirac wave operator, and 
\begin{equation}
D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} -igA_{\mu}
\end{equation}
is the covariant derivative.

> Now consider an axial U(1) transformation of the Dirac field, but with a spacetime dependent parameter $\alpha(x)$:
>   \begin{equation}
> \Psi(x) \rightarrow e^{-i\alpha (x)\gamma_{5}} \Psi(x)         \tag{77.12}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> \overline{\Psi}(x) \rightarrow \overline{\Psi}(x)e^{-i\alpha (x)\gamma_{5}}  \tag{77.13}
> \end{equation}
>   We can think of eqs. (77.12) and (77.13) as a change of integration variable in eq.(77.8); ... ...
>
> The change of variable in eqs.(77.12) and (77.13) is implemented by the functional matrix
>   \begin{equation}
> J(x, y) = \delta^{4}(x-y) e^{-i\alpha (x)\gamma_{5}}          \tag{77.17}
> \end{equation}
>   Because the path integral is over fermionic variables (rather than bosonic), we get a $(\det J)^{-1}$ (rather than $\det J$) for each of the transformations in eqs. (77.12) and (77.13), so that we have
>   \begin{equation}
>  \mathcal{D}\Psi \mathcal{D}\overline{\Psi}\rightarrow (\det J)^{-2}\mathcal{D}\Psi \mathcal{D}\overline{\Psi}                         \tag{77.18}
> \end{equation}

I don't understand this. Why is the Jacobian factor for fermionic variables $(\det J)^{-1}$ while that for bosonic ones $det J$?

Comment: That just comes down to how Grassmann variables are defined; they're not at all like ordinary numbers. This should be covered in detail early in the book.

Comment: ... chapter 44, eq. 44.18.

Comment: It can all be boiled down to the following fact about Grassmannian integrals $\int d\eta d{\bar \eta} e^{ - a \eta {\bar \eta} } = a$. The same formula for bosonic variables is $\int dz d{\bar z} e^{- a z {\bar z} } = \frac{2\pi}{a}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the full explanation comes from [Berezin integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) of Grassmann-odd variables.

1. One argument is that the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is a [supermatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermatrix), so that the Jacobian determinant is given by the [superdeterminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezinian).
2. Another argument is that [Grassmann-odd integration is the same as Grassmann-odd differentiation!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15786/2451) The Jacobian factor can therefore be understood from the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) of differentiation (rather than [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)).

Both arguments lead to that the Jacobian appears inverted.