# Fermionic measure in path integral

Tags: conventions, path-integral, integration, fermions, grassmann-numbers

When writing the fermionic path integral one arrives at an expression containing $\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}$ and $\mathcal{D}\psi$:

$$
\int \mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} \mathcal{D}\psi e^{iS}
$$

Usual derivations of this expression involve discretizing into time intervals and then inserting the realization of the identity operator using coherent states. Following this procedure, one defines

$$
\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} \mathcal{D}\psi := \lim_{n}\prod_{i}^n\textrm{d}\bar{\psi}_i\textrm{d}\psi_i
$$

I have a question at this point. What would happen if we exchange $\textrm{d}\bar{\psi}_i$ and $\textrm{d}\psi_i$ for all $i$? We would get a minus sign for each term, but what would happen with this minus sign in the limit $n\to\infty$?

My question is based on the fact that on books, notes and many resources $\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}$ and $\mathcal{D}\psi$ seemed to be exchanged under the integral sign without any justification, and people also write

$$
\int  \mathcal{D}\psi \mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} e^{iS}
$$

Clearly, for a finite number $n$ of $\textrm{d}\psi_i$'s such an exchange changes the integral by a factor $(-1)^n$, but what happens in the case of the path integral measure?

Suppose we have a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ given with a certain order for $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$? Let's say for instance $\mathcal{L}$ is normal ordered. Can we commute the measures as follows?

$$
\int \mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} \mathcal{D}\psi e^{iS}
 = \int  \mathcal{D}\psi \mathcal{D}\bar{\psi} e^{iS}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The relevant object in QFT is the generating functional
$Z[\eta, \bar{\eta}] = \int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi \, e^{i\{S[\psi, \bar{\psi}] +\int d^d x(\bar{\psi}(x) \eta(x)+\bar{\eta}(x) \psi(x)\}}$. The (Grassmann) fields $\eta$ and $\bar{\eta}$ are external  sources and the generating functional is normalized as $Z[0,0]=1$. Thus all your (potential) concerns are absorbed by this normalization condition. $\mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi$ should simply be seen as some symbolic notation for a translation invariant measure for the fermionic path integral.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a finite-dimensional [Berezin/Grassmann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) the order of the measure clearly do matter, as OP states. Since [the path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is supposed to be a continuum limit of a finite-dimensional integral, it is in principle also affected. However, we can avoid this sign ambiguity if we always increase the discretization with an even number of pairs $(\psi_i, \bar{\psi}_i)$.
2. Be aware that different authors have

   - different ordering conventions for measure + integrand, and
   - [different sign conventions for evaluating a 1-dimensional Berezin/Grassmann integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15786/2451).

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; chapter 44. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).